# Gradle build error: SAXParseException

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, saxparser, android-build

on building the app, i get following error:

```
Error:org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 0; columnNumber: 0; 
cvc-pattern-valid: Value 'build-tools;23.0.0 rc3' 
is not facet-valid with respect to pattern '[a-zA-Z0-9_\-;.]+' for type 'segmentListType'.
```

build.gradle of module level gradle:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ms.demo.map"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
}
```

The error remains even after cleaning the app. The structure of package does not match the `applicationId` described in gradle file. I am using latest version of Android Studio (2.0 Preview 9).

Comment: remove the space before 'apply plugin: 'com.android.application'' and rebuild the project, the error will be gone

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The error itself clearly explains what is wrong here:  `is not facet-valid with respect to pattern '[a-zA-Z0-9_\-;.]+' for type 'segmentListType'.`

Just remove the **space** before `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` and rebuild the project again.

Comment: so it didn't solve your problem , so you down vote it? without even posting your code.

Answer (score 8):

I have same problem after updating **android studio 2.0 beta 2** and gradle. for solution please follow bellow steps

1. Navigate to SDK Path.
2. Open Build-tools directory.
3. Remove **23.0.0-preview** from build-tools directory.
4. Rename **build-tools-21.1.2** to **21.1.2**

[image: AndroidSdk Build-tools directory]

Done.

Answer (score 5):

I encountered this problem also after updating to latest gradle. Simply go to `$ANDROID_HOME/build-tools/`and remove the 23.0.0 rc3 directory fixed the errors.

Answer (score 0):

I use latest version and I change this `details.useVersion '25.3.0'` to

```
details.useVersion '26.0.0'
```

and it work for me