# Gradle build Error or Bug in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I Followed [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34814536/5896744) to fix, when Android studio was giving me error **Gradle plugin is old** ,  now there is tinny problem now i am getting error **SAXParseException** here is the message of error.

```
Error:org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 0; columnNumber: 0; cvc-pattern-valid: Value 'build-tools;23.0.0 rc3' is not facet-valid with respect to pattern '[a-zA-Z0-9_\-;.]+' for type 'segmentListType'.
```

This is my **build.gradle(Module:app)**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.jutt.fyp.isec"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
}
```

**build.gradle(Project: Test)**:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-beta4'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I tried following [SO answer fix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35115442/5896744) and it didn't worked , i think there is something wrong or again updated ?

Comment: Try  buildToolsVersion '23.0.2' instead of buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

Comment: no effect , same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove this

```
$ANDROID_HOME/build-tools/and remove the 23.0.0-preview directory fixed the errors.
```

Example: In windows

```
C:\Users\Sharma\Desktop\xxx\Android\sdk\build-tools
```

Hope this helps

Comment: there is no **23.0.0-rc3** , there is **23.0.0-preview** and **23.0.2** folders.

Comment: should i remove any of these? mentioned above?

Comment: only remove  23.0.0-preview and let me know this

Comment: deleting `23.0.0-preview` directory fixed my issue , thanks

Answer (score 0):

Removing both 23.0.0-preview/ (as gvsharma pointed out) and 23.0.0_rc1/ solved my issue.

Ex.

```
[root@cobalt Sdk]# ls
add-ons  build-tools  docs  extras  licenses  lldb  ndk-bundle  platforms  platform-tools  samples  SDK Readme.txt  sources  system-images  temp  tools
[root@cobalt Sdk]# cd build-tools/
[root@cobalt build-tools]# ls
17.0.0  18.0.1  18.1.0  18.1.1  19.0.1  19.0.2  19.0.3  19.1.0  20.0.0  21.0.0  21.0.1  21.0.2  21.1.2  22.0.1  23.0.0-preview  23.0.0_rc1  23.0.1  23.0.2  android-4.4  android-4.4W
[root@cobalt build-tools]# rm -rf 23.0.0-preview/
[root@cobalt build-tools]# rm -rf 23.0.0_rc1
```